# Puedo modificar el value de un input al escribir una cantidad de caracteres?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal, y quería saber si es posible agregar un guión(-) al escribir una cantidad de caracteres determinados en el input por ejemplo:

Tengo el input:

```
<input type="text" name="codigo_cliente" id="id_codigo_cliente">
```

Y la idea es que al escribir por ejemplo "123" automáticamente se ponga un guión y quede "123-", eso solo es un ejemplo, no debe ser el "123" específicamente. He intendado el siguiente código JS con Jquery:

```
var idco = $("input#id_codigo_cliente");

if(idco.value == 3){
   $("input#id_codigo_cliente").value("-");
}
```

Pero como es de esperar... el código no funciona. Espero alguien me pueda ayudar, Gracias de antemano!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con jquery podria ser así:

```js
// jquery
var idco = $("input#id_codigo_cliente");

idco.keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode !== 8) {
    value = idco.val()
    if (value.length == 3) {
      idco.val(value + '-');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="codigo_cliente" id="id_codigo_cliente">
```

Y con vanilla javascript (javascript puro) lo que buscas seria algo así:

```js
// vanilla javascript
var idco = document.getElementById('id_codigo_cliente')

idco.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  const key = event.key;
  if (key !== "Backspace") {
    if (idco.value.length == 3) {
      idco.value = idco.value + '-';
    }
  }
}, false)
```

```html
<input type="text" name="codigo_cliente" id="id_codigo_cliente">
```

Comment: @Christian Pues a mi no me sucede, es decir, si se intenta solo borrar el guión entonces vuelve a aparecer, eso esta claro, y no te deja borrar con la tecla de retroceso más allá. Y eso ocurre en ambos casos. Pero si seleccionas todo el input lo puedes borrar sin problemas, o si mueves el cursor con el raton o el teclado tambien.  No se reproducir este bug que dices. (uso Firefox, a ver si va a ser eso.. pues no, en chrome tambien me funciona como digo)

Comment: Creo la idea no es con un valor especifico, si no en cierto numero de caracteres, por ejemplo al 3ro y entonces poner el - . O siguiendo un patron especifico

Comment: @StialManstike quizas tienes razón, pero eso no lo especifica el OP, ya lo aclarará si quiere.  Yo me ciño a lo que he leido en la pregunta actual, que ponia especificamente `por ejemplo "123"`

Comment: @masterguru bueno si, yo lo decia por el titulo de la pregunta, pero si, ya se aclarara,  de cualquier manera con la respuesta ya se puede guiar de mas.

Comment: @StialManstike vaya, pues tienes razon, no me leí el título (algun dia deberia leermelos mejor, siempre me pasa :-))... pues vaya... toca rehacer un poco el código!  bien visto

Comment: @StialManstike Pues ya esta, he editado la respuesta, gracias de nuevo :-)

Comment: Gracias!! solo una pregunta, si en lugar del "123" quisiera que fuera el valor que el usuario escribiera, por ejemplo el usuario podría escribir "456" o "abc" o cualquier otro tipo de caracter, o sea, no quiero que el "123" sea estable. Se puede?

Comment: @LinenBen17 recarga esta página para ver que ya habia actualizado mi respuesta y he modificado el código para que lo haga cuando son determinado número de caracteres (he puesto 3) pues me avisaron que tu titulo pedia un numero determinado de caracteres y no lo habia visto. Por lo tanto revisa de nuevo mi respuesta y dime si es suficiente ahora o necesitas algo mas

Comment: Listo!!! MUCHAS GRACIAS.

Comment: de nada, me alegro que te haya servido :-)

Comment: Una pregunta más, al momento de que intento borrar, el guión no es borrado:( y si me muevo para solo eliminar los tres caracteres se agregan más guiones, se puede arreglar eso?:/

Comment: @LinenBen17 recarga la página de nuevo y prueba el nuevo código de mi respuesta a ver si así te vale (es que lo quereis todo!!! :-))

Comment: Listo muchas gracias:'3